# Help identifying an unknown SOIC-8 memory chip

Tags: identification, spi, soic

I'm trying to dump the memory from a device for debugging.

Based on what I know of the microcontroller (an ANYKA AK3918EN080) and the debug info returned from my failed attempts to dump the memory I presume it is some kind of SPI memory chip (but I could be incorrect so don't hesitate to suggest it is not) that won't read properly with a simple clip-on programming tool while attached to the rest of the circuit. I've had no luck searching for this part based on the numbers I can read in order to get a datasheet.

Does anyone know what this part is and where I can get the datasheet?

The unknown chip with MCU for context:

[image: unkown-chip-with-mcu]

Closeup of the unknown chip

[image: crop-3]

More pictures are available but the texture of the chip and the low contrast ink makes it hard to get good pictures of the finer detail with the cameras and magnification tools I have on hand.

Update:

My best guess at the numbers is AK2105 25V264AS16 EFP184 but as stated earlier, its a little hard to read so I'm not 100% confident these are definitely the correct numbers. I'm also trying to avoid de-soldering if possible since I'm not as confident in my skills soldering SOIC and smaller pitches.

Comment: What are the numbers on it? It be helpful if you add them to the question. And I assume you looked up the SOC datasheet and pinout that most likely corresponds it using your ic in question as spi flash? Lift it out of circuit to get an accurate result.

Comment: Try taking the pic from a different angle and with different lighting to get a better indication of the part markings.

Comment: Don't guess. Wipe off the dust so you can see better. 25xx64 would make a good assumption that it is a SPI flash, maybe 64 Mbits.